# Python Curl request with access token not working

Tags: python, authentication, curl, python-requests, access-token

I am running below API query using curl I am getting json response.

```
curl -X POST   -H 'Content-Type: application/json'   -H 'X-Metabase-Session: sdfeffff-sdfdf-ffff-ffff-fffffffff'   https://dash.test.sh/api/card/140/query/json
```

But when I am trying to run same query using python requests I am getting response

```
"API endpoint does not exist."
```

Below is the python code which I am trying

```
import requests

url = 'https://dash.test.sh/api/card/140/query/json'
header = {
   'X-Metabase-Session': 'sdfeffff-sdfdf-ffff-ffff-fffffffff'
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=header)

print (response.text)
```

I expect actual json content

Answer (score 0):

curl is using `Post` and you are using `get`, the issue is there:

```
response = requests.post(url, headers=header)
```

Answer (score 0):

With curl, you are doing a POST request but in Python you are calling GET method of same API. And possibly, the GET method does not exists for the API.

So just change your Python code
From `requests.get` to `requests.post`